# AES file encryption with PBKDF2. Safe parameters?

Tags: aes, symmetric, pbkdf-2, file-encryption

I'm developing an application that will use public key authentication to contact some webservice. So the user has his keypair on his computer, and I want that file to be encrypted using AES with a key derived from a user's password.

I'm wondering if I'm using relatively "safe" parameters and way of writing the file.

Here are the PBKDF2 and AES parameters:

- PBKDF2 Iterations : 1024
- PBKDF2 Hash function : SHA256
- PBFDF2 Salt size : 256 bits
- PBKDF2 Derived key size : 256 bits
- AES Cipher mode : CFB

Here is how the file is written:

- Salt (Hex encoded)
- Return line
- IV (Hex encoded)
- Return line
- Encrypted file content (Hex encoded, encrypted using AES in CFB mode and the key derived from the user's password)

Maybe what's missing here is a HMAC (with SHA256, for example) to "guarantee" that the file hasn't been tampered with. Here's how probably I'd append it to the file, after "Encrypted file content":

- Return line
- HMAC-SHA256 with the content's encryption key

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1024 iterations is very low. If you can afford the performance hit, use a larger value. On a desktop computer you should be able to afford a million iterations.

Comment: increase iterations, reduce salt size. You do not need to encrypt the public key, but it should be authenticated. Possibly use OCB or GCM for 1 pass authenticated encryption.

Comment: "HMAC-SHA256 with the content's encryption key" - naughty. Never use the same key for two different crypto primitives.  Upon completion of your PBKDF2 rounds, perform a final round, but ask for 512 bits of output.  Use the first 256 bits for the encryption key, and the rest for the HMAC key.  More info [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5630/deriving-keys-for-symmetric-encryption-and-authentication).  As mentioned, if it's available, authenticated encryption such as CCM, EAX, GCM or OCB is also a good option.

Comment: @hunter one has to be careful about that. If one directly requests more than the natural size from PBKDF2 it can increase the cost for the defender but not for the attacker. Personally I like HKDF-Expand for this step.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - yup, hence 512 bits of output only for the final round (256 bits for every other round). I'm a big fan of HKDF too - but seeing as though PBKDF2 is required here anyway, it seems cleaner to me to use it for the final step.

Comment: @hunter Not entirely sure what you mean by "only the final round". Do you want to run PBKDF2 with 1 iteration on the output of PBKDF2 with many iterations?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I'm pretty sure we're on the same page:  perform as many iterations of PBKDF2 as tolerable requesting output equal to the native size of the underlying hash, and then a final single iteration requesting however many bytes are required.

Comment: I would also store the number of iterations in the file (that was used for this particular file), in case you will change it later on. Later files will be encrypted with higher number of iterations, but the older files can still be decrypted. For that matter other non-secret parameters can be stored for backward compatibility as well, such as PBKDF2 hash function used etc.

Answer (score 2):

As this question is still on the list of "questions without answers", I'll quickly answer it (Basically repeating all of the above comments).

1. Increase iteration count to something larger (1 Million?)
2. You [don't want to](https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2001/21390309.pdf) attach your HMAC of the plain-text after the contents. Rather authenticate either the ciphertext or (even better) use CCM/EAX/GCM mode.
3. Store the PBKDF's params in the header of the file.
4. Don't use PBKDF2 if possible. Rather use scrypt (best choice currently, for the next weeks), bcrypt (if no other option) or some of the [PHC finalists](https://password-hashing.net/candidates.html).

Comment: I'd stay with PBKDF2, bcrypt and scrypt for several more years. I don't consider the review the candidates received during the PHC competition sufficient to be really confident in their security.